# How to forcekill all proceses with same name except one with batch program?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I want forcekill all app (svchost.exe) with

```
@echo off

TASKKILL /F /IM Notepad.exe

pause
```

[image: task manager]

But how do I kill all process with the name  `svchost.exe` except one like order by command line name or path for example I don't want to kill  `svchost.exe` with command line  `C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k WerScvGroup` with batch file.

Comment: It is `svchost` and don't do this.

Comment: Why are you not using the correct mechanism to shut down services - the service control manager?

Comment: Don't ever try to kill this process ! please read this carefully => [What Is the Service Host Process (svchost.exe) and Why Are So Many Running?](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-svchostexe-and-why-is-it-running/)

Comment: @Hackoo sorry , its just example , i just want kill another exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wmic Path win32_process Where not "CommandLine Like 'C:\Windows\System32\scvhost.exe -k WerScvGroup' and name='scvhost.exe'" Call Terminate
```

or

```
wmic Path win32_process Where not "CommandLine Like 'C:\Windows\System32\scvhost.exe -k WerScvGroup' and name='scvhost.exe'" delete
```

not tested.