# How to kill same name processes by differing them by their parameter? in BATCH / .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic, taskkill

*Henlo smarter folks.*

While having fun with automating some workflows [im doing this in **batch** (/ vba)], btw this means if you think its better / easier to perform this in vba hit me, i faced the problem of using `taskkill` for multiple processes of the same name.
First i tried to circumvent this by using their `pids`'s, but i figured that this wont work because it changes everytime a process restarts, at least the ones i look for do.

**In short**:

- When ive got two or more processes of the same name with parameters like

`example.exe -test abcd` **and**
`example.exe -testing`;

- How to kill **only** the first one?

In long ... :

For example, if i would do:

- `taskkill /f /im example.exe` this would crash or bsod the machine etc, or do;
- `taskkill /PID example_pid` this would prompt *an error not found* or maybe even kill the wrong process

The full batch looks like this:

test_autokill.bat

```
:start
    timeout 5
    taskkill /f /im example1.exe
    taskkill /f /im example2.exe
    taskkill /f /im *and so on*
goto start
```

- Additionally i guessed that i would have to use `tasklist` first to output processes including their parameters, but searching to do so failed completely.
- Also i am not sure about what i would have to do next especially because i wasnt able to perform if+else (i think it usually said 'dont know what else is') conditions with tasklist previously.

*Thanks for your knowledge*

EDIT 1

I was pointed to a [related Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381697) which wanted to do the "opposide" of. Tho i tried it without the "not" modidier.

All tries (below) replied the same error Message:

```
ERROR:
Description = The request is invalid.
```

My tries (in AdminCLI):

```
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like 'C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k NetworkService'" Call Terminate
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like 'C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k NetworkService'" Delete
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like 'C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k NetworkService' and name='svchost.exe'" Call Terminate
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like 'C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k NetworkService' and name='svchost.exe'" Delete
```

The original ones had a typo btw, scv instead of **svc**.

Comment: I get called out as doing ugly / bad formatting - despite me liking it usually. If you think so too feel free to improve it. I will be greatful for it.

Comment: [How to kill a service host process with command line?](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2315883-how-to-kill-a-service-host-process-with-command-line)

Comment: Does `tasklist /V /FI "ImageName eq example.exe"` return anything useful to identify the target process?

Comment: With Powershell to get Handle you can try like this way : `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'svchost.exe'" | ? {$_.CommandLine -match "svchost.exe -k NetworkService"} | select Handle,CommandLine`

Comment: What did you get with this command line : `wmic Process Where "CommandLine Like '%%-k NetworkService'" get Handle`

Comment: ```tasklist /V /FI "ImageName eq example.exe"``` is not useful enough (information). Because it only outputs the first parameter instead of the full commandline ...

Anyways ↓

Comment: ```wmic Process Where "CommandLine Like '%%-k NetworkService'" get Handle``` - WELL it works but it also does not work.  As soon as i look for different command lines which start with ```--``` or ```/``` or are just very long or use ```""``` somewhere in the middle it outputs ```no instance available``` or for the last one ```invalid parameter for this level```. It only works for ServiceHost-exe's so far.  Which is a great step forward but id be glad for further assistence. @Hackoo

Answer (score 0):

With a batch file, you can try like this way if you want to kill the first PID, you just remove the `echo` before the `Taskkill` command in this example :

---

```
@echo off
Set "WMIC_CMD=WMIC Process Where "CommandLine Like '%%-k NetworkService'" get Handle /Value"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('%WMIC_CMD%') do (
    @for /F "delims=" %%K in ("%%J") do (
        Set /A Count+=1
        set "Handle[!Count!]=%%K"
    )
)
@for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    echo %%i - !Handle[%%i]!
)
pause
REM IF You want to kill the first one
ECHO Taskkill /F /PID !Handle[1]!
pause
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great so far.  

But this also does not work very long commandlines which contain confusing (for win) symbols. Would it be possible to look for a partial match only. 

Like:  

Atm ```"CommandLine Like '%%-k anything'"``` matches only when inputting the full command line.  

Is it possible to find ```example.exe -channel=123456789``` with only entering ```"CommandLine Like '%%-channel'"```. On the premise that there is only one process with the commandline ```example.exe -channel```.

@Hackoo